# Python Pandas, Name error using eval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone explain to me why i get NameError when eval is executing ?

```
toEval = ""
for i in self.dtf.columns.values:
    if (self.lst.count(i) > 0):
        toEval = toEval + "self.dtf[[" + i + "]].dropna(),"


toEval = toEval[:len(toEval)-1]
t = eval(toEval)
```

Comment: You don't have an object named `self`? You need to copy and paste the error here.

Comment: Perhaps you should treat this as a sign that you *shouldn't be using `eval`, ever*.  You could much more easily achieve the same results by appending the values to a list, rather than appending the source code to generate the values to a string.

Comment: I have an object named self this is a part of a class. 
This is the full error message:
<string> in <module>()
NameError: name 'group1' is not defined

I use eval because i do not know what columns the user will want to use.
I will check if i can use a list.

Comment: @jasonharper
I used a list and now everything is running normally.
What I can not figure out is that in panda 0.19 the code works fine. But when I went to 0.20 it stopped